# How to create a plot like this - Days and Symptoms over time? (Example Included)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, visualization

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a graph like this using ggplot2 or any other R package: [image]

I'd like to be able to do something similar regarding symptoms overtime. Do these plots have a certain name?

Thanks y'all!

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. You could do it as a heat map. If you have any data or dummy data then we could show you how to do it. Otherwise, it’s likely this question will be closed as too broad.

Comment: Thank you, this put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Allan Cameron for the heatmap suggestion. To answer my own question, I found this link helpful and think it can put me on the right track: https://www.littlemissdata.com/blog/heatmaps